# Amazon EC2 AMI for mule CE

Tags: amazon-ec2, mule, amazon-ami

Is any one aware of public AMI for Mule 3.x.x CE. I am looking for options to deploy CE Mule on Amazon EC2. Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about any public AMI.
But you could easily create your own.
Amazon Linux AMIs have openjdk pre-installed.
[It's not officially supported](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Installing+and+Endorsing+the+JDK), but it's still able to run Mule CE.

Just do:

```
wget http://dist.codehaus.org/mule/distributions/mule-standalone-3.2.1.tar.gz
tar xzvf mule-standalone-3.2.1.tar.gz
cd mule-standalone-3.2.1
bin/mule start
```

Hope this helps.